# How to replace Servlet Filters already defined (replacing legacy doWithWebDescriptor with doWithSpring)

Tags: grails

I'm trying to upgrade a Grails plugin from version 2.3.4 to 4.0.11. It uses a syntax that is no longer supported to replace filters with names `sitemesh` and `urlMapping` with its own filters.

The code below uses a DSL for xml. It replaces xml nodes in the final generated `web.xml`.

```
def doWithWebDescriptor = { xml ->
    def pageFilter = xml.filter.find { it.'filter-name'.text() == 'sitemesh' }
    def urlMappingFilter = xml.filter.find { it.'filter-name'.text() == 'urlMapping' }

    def grailsVersion = GrailsUtil.grailsVersion

    // Grails 1.3.x & Grails 2.0.x
    def pageFilterClass = "org.zkoss.zk.grails.web.ZKGrailsPageFilter"
    def urlMappingFilterClass = "org.zkoss.zk.grails.web.ZULUrlMappingsFilter"

    if(grailsVersion.startsWith("2")) {
        pageFilter.'filter-class'.replaceNode {
            'filter-class'(pageFilterClass)
        }
        urlMappingFilter.'filter-class'.replaceNode {
            'filter-class'(urlMappingFilterClass)
        }

        //
        // Require a legacy config for servlet version
        //
        if(application.metadata.getServletVersion() >= '3.0') {
            pageFilter.'filter-class' + {
                'async-supported'('true')
            }
            urlMappingFilter.'filter-class' + {
                'async-supported'('true')
            }
        }
    } else {
        pageFilter.'filter-class'.replaceBody(pageFilterClass)
        urlMappingFilter.'filter-class'.replaceBody(urlMappingFilterClass)
    }
}
```

**What I tried so far**

The code below uses Grails plugin configuration to register filters with spring's `FilterRegistrationBean`. I'm following [Grails official documentation](http://docs.grails.org/3.3.11/guide/plugins.html#hookingIntoRuntimeConfiguration).

```
Closure doWithSpring() { { ->
    boolean supportsAsync = this.grailsApplication.metadata.getServletVersion() >= "3.0"

    pageFilter(FilterRegistrationBean) {
        name = "sitemesh"
        filter = bean(org.zkoss.zk.grails.web.ZKGrailsPageFilter)
        urlPatterns = ["/*"]
        order = Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE
        asyncSupported = supportsAsync
    }

    urlMappingFilter(FilterRegistrationBean) {
        name = "urlMapping"
        filter = bean(org.zkoss.zk.grails.web.ZULUrlMappingsFilter)
        urlPatterns = ["/*"]
        order = Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE
        asyncSupported = supportsAsync
    }
}}
```

**How can I replicate the legacy code with RegistrationBeans?**

Also, I don't know if any of these filters got deprecated by Grails. I would like to know if there are any other replacements, if possible.

[Here's the project](https://github.com/maiconandsilva/zk-grails) in case anyone wants more context.

Comment: "I don't know if any of these filters got deprecated by Grails" - Do you mean the `urlMappingFilter` and `pageFilter`?

Comment: Yes. The previous code replace filter nodes with `'filter-name'` attributes `sitemesh` and `urlMapping`. I'm trying to find a replacement for this code. Thank you for asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debugging the older version of the plugin I came up with the following:

```
pageFilter(FilterRegistrationBean) {
    name = "sitemesh"
    filter = bean(ZKGrailsPageFilter)
    urlPatterns = ["/*"]
    order = OrderedFilter.REQUEST_WRAPPER_FILTER_MAX_ORDER + 50
    asyncSupported = supportsAsync
    dispatcherTypes = EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.ERROR)
}

urlMappingFilter(FilterRegistrationBean) {
    name = "urlMapping"
    filter = bean(ZULUrlMappingsFilter)
    urlPatterns = ["/*"]
    order = OrderedFilter.REQUEST_WRAPPER_FILTER_MAX_ORDER + 60
    asyncSupported = supportsAsync
    dispatcherTypes = EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.FORWARD)
}
```

Added the `dispatcherTypes` and changed the order assuming these would be the last filters where the 'pageFilter' should be placed before the 'urlMappingFilter' in the filter chain.